# can't use galaxy s3 as a usb storage device

Tags: 12.10, gnome, command-line, usb, storage

Hi im trying to move some files from my phone to my netbook via usb  its running Ubuntu 12.10 (gnome shell).
When I plug my s3 it seems to recognise what it is but can't read any of its contents. I just want to use it as if it were a storage device and move some files to my netbook can anyone help with this issue please.

Comment: What USB mode did you put your phone in? MTP, PTP, mass storage, etc. If configured as plain mass storage device it should appear like a USB flash drive in Ubuntu.

Comment: follow - http://www.webupd8.org/2013/01/upgrade-to-gvfs-with-mtp-support-in.html

Comment: When you connect your phone to a system using a USB, it by default starts charging. to transfer data between your phone and system you need to unlock your phone and bring down the top menu where you will see a USB symbol waiting with a statement "Turn ON USB" tap on it and select to turn ON then depending on your device setting the device gets detected.

Comment: I believe newer devices don't have msc,and ubuntu doesn't support mtp very well.